# Virtual console size increased after upgrading to RHEL 6.8

Tags: vmware-esxi, rhel6, console

After updating some VMware virtual machines to **RHEL 6.8** (kernel 2.6.32-642) it appears that the size of the virtual console has been increased -- it is huge.

No X server is running in the console, i.e., it is a classical text-based linux console.

When I log in through the virtual console, the values of `LINES` and `COLUMNS` variables are:

```
COLUMNS=160
LINES=48
```

How can I resize the console?

Thanx in advance

**update 1**

I googled this issue and found a lot of solutions using the `vga=` kernel option in `grub.conf`. I have tried that but it does not work; although that option does appear in `/proc/cmdline` after the reboot -- it is not ignored.

I have found these two lines in the `dmesg` output:

```
Console: colour VGA+ 80x25
console [tty0] enabled
```

but a lot of lines below, I have found:

```
[drm] DMA map mode: Using physical TTM page addresses.
[drm] Capabilities:
[drm]   Rect copy.
[drm]   Cursor.
[drm]   Cursor bypass.
[drm]   Cursor bypass 2.
[drm]   8bit emulation.
[drm]   Alpha cursor.
[drm]   Extended Fifo.
[drm]   Multimon.
[drm]   Pitchlock.
[drm]   Irq mask.
[drm]   Display Topology.
[drm]   GMR.
[drm]   Traces.
[drm]   GMR2.
[drm]   Screen Object 2.
[drm]   Command Buffers.
[drm] Max GMR ids is 64
[drm] Max number of GMR pages is 65536
[drm] Max dedicated hypervisor surface memory is 163840 kiB
[drm] Maximum display memory size is 8192 kiB
[drm] VRAM at 0xd8000000 size is 8192 kiB
[drm] MMIO at 0xd0800000 size is 256 kiB
[drm] global init.
[TTM] Zone  kernel: Available graphics memory: 8167096 kiB
[TTM] Zone   dma32: Available graphics memory: 2097152 kiB
[TTM] Initializing pool allocator
[TTM] Initializing DMA pool allocator
[drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[drm] No driver support for vblank timestamp query.
[drm] Screen Objects Display Unit initialized
[drm] width 1280
[drm] height 768
[drm] bpp 32
[drm] Fifo max 0x00040000 min 0x00001000 cap 0x0000077f
[drm] Using command buffers with DMA pool.
[drm] DX: no.
fbcon: svgadrmfb (fb0) is primary device
Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 160x48
[drm] Initialized vmwgfx 2.9.0 20150810 for 0000:00:0f.0 on minor 0
```

You can see how the **`drm` module sets up the graphical screen size (`1280x768@32`) and text scree size (`160x48`)**. I know nothing about this `drm` module. The following command line shows something about it:

```
# lsmod|grep drm
drm_kms_helper        127219  1 vmwgfx
drm                   362893  4 vmwgfx,ttm,drm_kms_helper
i2c_core               29132  3 i2c_piix4,drm_kms_helper,drm
```

I will look for information about `drm` module.

**update 2**

I confirm that this issue is introduced in RHEL 6.8.
I had updated a RHEL 6.1 box up to RHEL 6.7 and console size had suffered no change.

Later, when I have updated to RHEL 6.8, the console has become huge.

Comment: @GregL, I added my advances as **update 1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*In a nutshell:*

Try disabling VMware's `svgadrmfb` framebuffer driver. I had the same change in resolution and discovered that the framebuffer became enabled after an update on one of my virtual machines.

*Now for the long answer...*

I came across your question in search of an answer to the *same exact* issue, although in my case the display resolution had changed when I did a reboot after automatic updates on a TurnKey Linux appliance (Debian-based). Let's call this *vm1*.

After digging through the kernel log (`dmesg`) and comparing it to the log of another VM, *vm2* (which still had the original resolution), I found *vm1* had the additional following lines.

```
[    2.033291] [drm] width 1280
[    2.033305] [drm] height 768
[    2.033318] [drm] bpp 32
[    2.050045] [drm] Fifo max 0x00040000 min 0x00001000 cap 0x0000007f
[    2.085691] fbcon: svgadrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    2.088207] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 160x48
```

I checked *vm2* and confirmed that it had not loaded the `svgadrmfb` driver (from the absence of `/dev/fb0`).

I found the following article on how to disable the framebuffer:
http://kb.digium.com/articles/FAQ/How-to-disable-the-Linux-frame-buffer-if-it-s-causing-problems

I tested the suggested kernel boot parameters:

- `vga=normal`
- `nofb`
- `nomodeset`
- `video=vesafb:off` (Actually, I tried `video=svgadrmfb:off` instead, but it didn't work anyway.)
- `i915.modeset=0`

In my case it was `nomodeset` that worked for me. Once I made this discovery, I made it permanent as follows (I deviated from step 4 in the linked page). After looking at the `/etc/grub.d/10_linux` file, I realized that the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` variable in `/etc/default/grub` was all that needed changing. (Also suggested in [AskUbuntu #19486](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-boot-parameter).)

In my case the variable was:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="consoleblank=0"
```

I changed this line to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="consoleblank=0 nomodeset"
```

After making that change, update GRUB's configuration:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Then issue an `init 6` to reboot.

If your system was previously not loading `svgadrmfb` either, then the screen resolution should now return when the framebuffer is disabled.

```
root@server:~# tput cols
80
root@server:~# tput lines
25
```

Also, once your system is booted, you can verify the effective kernel boot command:

```
root@server:~# cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-amd64 root=/dev/mapper/turnkey-root ro consoleblank=0 nomodeset
```

Answer (score 2):

I opened [this post](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/2450631) in the RedHat discussion and a support member suggested me [this other post](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/81423). I tried the different solutions shown and adding the kernel option

```
vmwgfx.enable_fbdev=0
```

in the `grub` configuration file worked.

Thanks everyone.